# Teradata CASE with CAST

Tags: teradata

I have the following statement. My expectation is that if price is less that 1.00 then show 4 significant digits, otherwise show 2.

```
Select CAST(10.99 AS DECIMAL(38,4)) C
    , CAST(10.99 AS DECIMAL(38,2)) D
    , CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(38,4)) AS LESS
    , CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(38,2)) AS GREATER
    , (CASE
         WHEN CAST(10.99 AS DECIMAL(38,4)) < CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(38,4)) THEN 
            CAST(10.99 AS DECIMAL(38,4))
         ELSE CAST(10.99 AS DECIMAL(38,2))
       END) AS PRICE_FORMATTED
FROM  MY_PRICE_TBL ;
```

Giving the result below:

```
C        D       LESS    GREATER    PRICE_FORMATTED
10.9900  10.99    1.0000  1.00       10.9900
```

I am explicitly CASTing everything in this example to show that LESS and GREATER columns are being casted correctly but the formatting is being picked up wrong. I expect PRICE_FORMATTED value to be the same as value in Col D

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PRICE_FORMATTED` *is* the same *value* as `D`, just it's fractional precision is different.

A CAST returns a single column and this column has a datatype. When different datatypes are returned by WHEN the parser chooses the best match. Of course a decimal (38,4) and (38,2) are different and then the one with higher fractional digits is used.

You might try the NUMBER datatype which doesn't display trailing zeroes, but then `10.9000` will be shown as `10.9`, too.

Comment: makes sense why it is happening now. Thanks.